# Axis2 Class Cast Exception

Tags: apache-axis

I am currently using JBoss6.0 and have an webapplication deployed that makes use of an WebService on a remote system. Now after deploying and when trying to call a method on the webservice, I get the following error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOnlyMessageReceiver cannot be cast
>   to org.apache.axis2.engine.MessageReceiver

Answer (score 4):

The error occurs when the Axis2 jar files are located in **multiple locations** within the classpath (perhaps even with different versions) of the JBoss server.

If you use maven you can add `<scope>provided</scope>` to the Axis2 dependencies of your project to ensure the libs exist only in one single location within the classpath.